# mkdir different behavior in Makefile and Terminal

Tags: makefile, mkdir

I am facing a problem with mkdir command in Linux Ubuntu 14. I want to create multiple directories at same level, So in Makefile I have done something like this.

```
mkdir -v /opt/dir/{dir1,dir2,dir3}
```

and its output is like

```
mkdir: created directory '/opt/dir/{dir1,dir2,dir3}'
```

But when I ran this command direct on Terminal, I got expected result.

```
'mkdir: created directory /opt/dir/dir1'
'mkdir: created directory /opt/dir/dir2'
'mkdir: created directory /opt/dir/dir3'
```

I am unable to find the problem.

Any suggestion will be helpful.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that the problem is not that mkdir works differently, but that the shell you're using in terminal differs from what is used to by make to run your commands. By default make (gnu or other) uses /bin/sh.

Try to add `SHELL=/bin/bash` to your makefile.

Comment: Setting `SHELL` is a *bad idea* as it makes the makefile unportable.

Answer (score 1):

Brace expansion with `{a,b,c}` is a non-portable shell extension that the `/bin/sh` used by `make` does not understand. You should spell out the directories as in

```
mkdir -v /opt/dir/dir1 /opt/dir/dir2 /opt/dir/dir3
```

or use

```
for d in dir1 dir2 dir3; do mkdir -v /opt/dir/$$d; done
```

This illustrates once again the importance of portable shell programming. [Know what is POSIX shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_01) and what is not.